# How to sum timestamps Python

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I am using the awful library *datetime* and I trying to do what should be very easy. I have a collection of timestamps in my video file, and I want to simply subtract start_time from end_time and then take the sum of all and output, the total time of the video file.  My data in my video file looks like this

```
<p begin="00:02:42.400" end="00:02:43.080" style="s2">product_1</p>
```

So my code,

```
start_time = dt.strptime(begin, '%H:%M:%S.%f')
endie_time = dt.strptime(end, '%H:%M:%S.%f')

diff += endie_time-start_time
```

What I am trying to do is to keep adding up 'diff'

I get this error,

**UnboundLocalError: local variable 'diff' referenced before assignment**

I think the error is because diff is a datetime object and it is not an integer. But then when I do `int(diff), nothing works.

How can I do this simple task? I appreciate any help I can get on this annoying problem.

Thanks

Comment: Since you use `+=`, you need to give variable `diff` an initial value.

Comment: @Alanhaha When I did diff = endie_time-start_time then after I tried diff++ it says unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'datetime.timedelta'

Comment: Why are you doing diff++? It's not required for your case right?

Comment: Use `diff = datetime.timedelta()` as the initial value.

Comment: can you add a full example with your data, from input to output?

Comment: Python's `datetime` library is anything but *"awful"*. [`SELECT` isn't broken!](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/)

Comment: @kederrac <p begin="00:02:42.400" end="00:02:43.080" style="s2">product_1</p>

Comment: @DanD. That eliminates the error, but it is not adding every instance, I have this code in a for loop and need to increment 'diff'

Comment: @MattQuaine You shouldn't increment the `diff` here. You have to just iterate over the `for` loop with a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fundamental issue here is that the `datetime` module deals with real-world wall clock times, whereas you're trying to deal with *durations*. The only really applicable class in the `datetime` module to deal with your problem appropriately is therefore [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta), which essentially expresses durations. To parse your strings into a `timedelta`, you'll need to do so slightly manually:

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> h, m, s = '00:02:43.080'.split(':')
>>> timedelta(hours=int(h), minutes=int(m), seconds=float(s))
datetime.timedelta(seconds=163, microseconds=80000)
```

If you now have two such `timedelta`s, you can subtract them:

```
>>> end - start
datetime.timedelta(microseconds=680000)
```

And you can add them to an existing `timedelta`:

```
diff = timedelta()
diff += end - start
```

Complete example:

```
from datetime import timedelta

diff = timedelta()

def parse_ts(ts: str) -> timedelta:
    h, m, s = ts.split(':')
    return timedelta(hours=int(h), minutes=int(m), seconds=float(s))

timestamps = [('00:02:42.400', '00:02:43.080'), ...]

for start, end in timestamps:
    diff += parse_ts(end) - parse_ts(start)

print(diff)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the comments to the original question say, using
    X += Y 
requires that you have alredy defined X.

A possible fix would be:

```
import datetime as dt

diff = dt.timedelta(0)  # Initialize the diff with 0

start_time = dt.datetime.strptime(begin, '%H:%M:%S.%f')
endie_time = dt.datetime.strptime(end, '%H:%M:%S.%f')

diff += endie_time-start_time  # Accumulate the time difference in diff
```

Since it seems that you want to iterate over multiple star/end dates:

```
import datetime as dt

diff = dt.timedelta(0)  # Initialize the diff with 0

for begin_i, end_i in zip(begin, end):

    start_time = dt.datetime.strptime(begin_i, '%H:%M:%S.%f')
    endie_time = dt.datetime.strptime(end_i , '%H:%M:%S.%f')

    diff += endie_time-start_time  # Accumulate the time difference in diff
```

In both cases above, diff will be of the dt.timedelta type.

Comment: `dt` seems to refer to both `datetime.datetime` and also just `datetime` in your code…?!

Comment: Note that this will break if your timestamps exceed 24 hours. While this may not be a *typical* problem you'll encounter with average videos, it is a fundamental problem with using `datetime.datetime` for this task.

Comment: You are right about dt reffering to datetime and datetime.datetime I corrected it in code. Thank you.

Comment: I very nice observation about the 24hours problem. This seems to be a limitation coming from the `begin` and `end`  strings. I don't know if there is a way to work around it.

Comment: Yes, there is. Don't use `datetime` for working with what aren't wall-clock times. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60036362/476.

Comment: I can't comment to your answer, but it should be accepted instead of mine. I did not see the 24h problem coming.